# How do I insert proper std code in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a small project in which I am using mysql for my database, in which i need to input phone numbers with std codes.
The problem is in inserting proper std codes.

Suppose the std code is `0123` but while running the query it is only inserting `123`.
If it is 0275, it is only inserting 275.

but if it is `2210` it is properly inserting `2210`

i tried making it `"int", "bigint", "varchar"` but all in vain..

plz sggst to solve it..

Comment: `varchar` type should work in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this.It should work `varchar(5)`

Answer (score 0):

I usually store phone numbers as a BIGINT in E164 format.

E164 never start with a 0, with the first few digits being the country code.

```
+441234567890
+44 (0)1234 567890
01234 567890
```

etc. would be stored as `441234567890`.

> But my suggestion is you can use a **varchar** for a telephone number.
>   You do not need an int because you are not going to perform arithmetic
>   on the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**VARCHAR** will work in your case.

The only thing you have to make sure is, while inserting the data, you're traeting the data as string, that is enclosing with single quotes. Otherwise, you will again end up losing leading zeroes, doesn't matter you have VARCHAR as the datatype

```
INSERT INTO tab VALUES('0123');
```